# Unable to read image with FileReader (see Update 2)

Tags: javascript, jquery, filereader

I am trying read a image file selected by a `input[type=file]` field with this javascript code:

```
      var reader = new FileReader();
      var blob;
      reader.onloadend = function (e) {
        blob = e.target.result;
      }
      reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
```

but when I run the code in the browser, I am getting this error:

```
TypeError: Argument 1 of FileReader.readAsDataURL is not an object.
```

Anyone can see what's wrong here?

**UPDATE**

this is the code where this snippet is included. SHould given more context about what's causing the error, I hope:

```
  $('#submit').on('click', function(){
    var $form = $( 'form.form' ), url = $form.attr( "action" ), str = $form.serialize();
    $('input[type=file]').each(function(){
      var reader = new FileReader();
      var blob;
      reader.onloadend = function (e) {
        blob = e.target.result;
      }
      reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
      str = str + "\u0026" + $(this).attr("name") + "=" + blob;
    });
    var posting = $.post( url, str );
    posting.done(function(data){
      if(data == "") {
        $("#alerta_sucesso").css("display", "block");
      } else {
        $("#alerta_erro").find("#texto").text(data);
        $("#alerta_erro").css("display", "block");
      }
    });
  });
```

**UPDATE 2**

I manage to change the code and execute it without errors, but even so I can't store the image inside the variable `blob` to send this data to the server. The curretn code is this:

```
  $('#submit').on('click', function(){
    var $form = $( 'form.form' ), url = $form.attr( "action" ), str = $form.serialize();
    var input = $form.find('input[type=file]');
    $form.find('input[type=file]').each(function(){
      var id = $(this).attr("id");
      if(typeof id !== "undefined") {
        if(this.files.length > 0) {
          var reader = new FileReader();
          var blob;
          reader.onloadend = function (e) {
            blob = e.result;
          }
          reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
          str = str + "\u0026" + $(this).attr("name") + "=" + blob;
        }
      }
    });
    var posting = $.post( url, str );
    posting.done(function(data){
      if(data == "") {
        $("#alerta_sucesso").css("display", "block");
      } else {
        $("#alerta_erro").find("#texto").text(data);
        $("#alerta_erro").css("display", "block");
      }
    });
  });
```

I assume the problem now it's with the line:

```
blob = e.result;
```

Anyone knows what should be the right value for this?

Comment: Can you create a stacksnippets to demonstrate?

Comment: @guest271314 I update the question with the complete code where the snippet I post before was. I hope this could given a more broad context about what's causing the error.

Comment: @guest271314 What I want accomplish: submit the images selected by the `input` field with the rest of the text fields (right now, this is not happening, because the function $.serialize is not reading this `input[type=file]` fileds).

Comment: `onloadend` provides `.result` of `FileReader.readAsDataURL()` call asynchronously. Why do you send a query string and not use `FormData()`? Are there more than one `<input type="file">` elements in `document`? Can you include `html` at Question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I finally manage to solve this issue with this approach:

```
  var str = "";

  $('input[type=file]').on("change", function(){
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    var name = $(this).attr("name");
    if(typeof id !== "undefined") {
      if(this.files.length > 0) {
        reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onloadend = function () {
          str += "&" + name + "=" + this.result;
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
      }
    }
  });

  $('#submit').on('click', function(){
    var $form = $( 'form.form' );
    var url = $form.attr( "action" );
    str += $form.serialize();
    $.post(url, str, function(data){
      if(data == "") {
        $("#alerta_sucesso").css("display", "block");
      } else {
        $("#alerta_erro").find("#texto").text(data);
        $("#alerta_erro").css("display", "block");
      }
    });
  });
```

and now the image is being sent to server as a string which can be handled by the PropertyEditorSupport class; this is the thing I am trying make work right now.

Answer (score 2):

FileReader is asynchronous and the execution happens in a singular thread.

This means when this line is called (I can't see `str` being defined anywhere, if not, remember to set it to an initial string before appending it, ie. `var str = "";`):

```
str = str + "\u0026" + $(this).attr("name") + "=" + blob;
```

`blob` is not yet filled with any value yet as it need to wait for the entire function block to finish execution so the code inside the handler can be executed.

You need to build the resulting string from within the callback:

```
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onloadend = function() {
  str += "&" + $(this).attr("name") + "=" + this.result;
  // continue from here ...
};
reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
```

But `blob` is not a blob in this code (or `this.result` after my changes above), it's a string holding a data-uri at this point. You may need to encode your string first if this is intended to be part of a URI argument (see for example [encodeURIComponent](https://devdocs.io/javascript/global_objects/encodeuricomponent) - with images as data-uri you may also run into length limitations and will have to use POST).

If you need an actual blob you don't even need to use FileReader - simply use the file object which is also a blob (from `this.files[n]`).

Comment: some points: 1) `str` is defined in the beginning of the code - the second line, exactly. 2) I move `str += "&" + $(this).attr("name") + "=" + this.result;` inside the block as sugested, but the string only appears appended inside this block.

Comment: I just visualize `str` inside the `reader.onloadend = function() {...}` block and before `var posting = $.post( url, str );`. the last one is displayed first; the first one after. but when I check the browser's developer tools, this param is not included among the others.

Comment: @KleberMota "but the string only appears appended inside this block" this is expected and is as it should be. It's a async operation and the result can only (safely) be appended when the entire load has completed. As I indicated, you need to continue from within that handler block (ie. post the result etc.).

Answer (score 0):

With the limited information given, if you're trying to show the image in a div or img element, below shows two approaches.

### Solution 1

```js
$('input').change(function() {

  var fr = new FileReader;

  fr.onloadend = function() {
    $("#target").attr('src', fr.result);
  };
  console.log(this.files[0]);
  //fr.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file">
<img id="target">
```

### Solution 2

```js
$('input').change(function() {

  var fr = new FileReader;

  fr.onload = function() {
    var img = new Image;
    img.onload = function() {
      var c = document.getElementById("cvs");
      var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
      ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 200, 180);
    }
    img.src = fr.result;

  };
  console.log(this.files[0]);
  fr.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file">
<canvas id="cvs"></canvas>
```

These would read your file and you can get dynamically the file name and other properties.

Comment: Answer does not explain error described at OP. `javascript` at Question should return expected result.

Comment: Can't see what's wrong with his code. Its working fine and i gave two solutions due to a broad question he asked.

Comment: Can you reproduce error described at Question? What is issue with `javascript` at OP?

Comment: Tried to reproduce it but i'm nowhere near the original error. I only got is `TypeError: Failed to execute 'readAsDataURL' on 'FileReader': parameter 1 is not of type 'Blob'.` There must be something additional to his code or he should post stack trace of his error.

Comment: @Inuka I update the question with the complete code where the snippet I post before was. I hope this could given a more broad context about what's causing the error.

Comment: @KleberMota i will tale a look at that soon.

Comment: @Inuka What I want accomplish: submit the images selected by the `input` field with the rest of the text fields (right now, this is not happening, because the function $.serialize is not reading this `input[type=file]` fileds).